# Read and write same file concurrently

Tags: c++, file-io, concurrency

Please consider this picture:

```
                       Boundary
                          |
                          v
+-------------------------+---+
|   (Read only region)    |>>>| (Appending)
+-------------------------+---+
       ^    ^    ^            ^
       |    |    |            |
     Multiple readers   Single writer
```

Accessing a same file concurrently, we have several readers and
only one writer. The writer always writes at the end of the file -
it never re-write the bytes that have already written before. And
the readers may read random positions of the file but they never
overstep the boundary. When new bytes have been written, the
writer increases the boundary. In theory I think, if we have these
constraints we could read and write the same file at the same
time. This will be good for many cases.

My question is how to implement it in an easy way - I am not sure
what the filesystem could guarantee.

One idea is that to break the file into small buffers, and use
some lock-free algorithms. But the operating system already have
these buffers - from process caches to disk caches, and it's fit
in with paging memory system. Add a new layer of cache will bring
more memory copy times. And it's a bit complex.

Considering the language, without a lock we can't access a C++
file stream object from multiple threads safety. But if we use a
lock, it is synchronous access, not concurrent access.
Furthermore, I think a read-write lock will not work. While
several readers share the lock, the file cursor and other
internal variables of the stream object will have the data race
problem, because these variables will be changed when you read the
file, it's actually a write operation.

What do you think ? Is there some C++ libraries already did this ?

Comment: Why not have a read file pointer as a thread local storage ?

Comment: If you have multiple readers then surely you would have multiple file stream objects (one for each thread). That way you don't need to use any kind of locks.

Comment: I had a similar problem to this when I was working on a video capture/stream project some time ago ... the simplest solution I could come up with was to have a 'writer' object that kept track of the EOF pointer (or the pseudo EOF) and since our readers had a specific buffer size to read (16k chunks), I just had to add a little logic to check they didn't read past the pseudo-eof .. it only cost an unsigned variable and a lock on that to read it .. is there a reason you need the 'reading' of the file to be locked? Will the 'read-only' area ever be written over?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but since I have the exact same problem, I don't see the need for writing another one. Being very new to programming, it would be very useful to me if any (or all) of the commenters would elaborate a bit on their suggested solution and post it as an answer. Or maybe someone else can write a more detailed answer?